# Миграция с MySQL на PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, mysql

Как наилучшим образом с минимумом усилий перенести базу данных с MySQL на PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 6):

Несколько достойных источников по теме можно найти на [PostgreSQL вики](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL#MySQL) в разделе MySQL. Например:

- [How to make a proper migration from MySQL to PostgreSQL](http://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=Programming:Converting_MySQL_to_PostgreSQL#Convert_and_Import)
- [Conversion tool for migrating from MySQL to PostgreSQL](http://www.pgsql.com/download/)