# Как перенести базу из Mysql в PostgreSQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Решил попробовать перенести базу из Mysql в PostgreSQL - сделал sql файл, но из отличия в синтаксисе-это не работает.
Читал [Миграция с MySQL на PostgreSQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/338619/) , но не разобрался что-то.
Как легко перенести базу ?
Посоветуйте хорошую IDE для PostgreSQL ?

Comment: База, случайно не для Ruby on Rails приложения? Вернее, используется ли она в Ruby on Rails приложении?

Comment: нет.  для golang

Comment: Если работа с базой данных происходит через ORM, то, возможно, есть библиотека для используемой ORM, которая позволяет сделать дамп базы, например, в YAML, или сериализовать данные, через адаптер для MySQL, а затем импортировать их через Postgres адаптер в базу данных Postresql.

Comment: ну, наверняка самая большая сложность будет не с данными, а со схемой. я бы с неё и начал, отключив данные с помощью опции `--data`. а когда всю схему полностью бы перенес, занялся данными — противоположная по смыслу опция: `--no-create-info`. ну, и, как пишут по ссылке, всё обязательно с опцией `--compatible=postgresql`. / это я про опции для `mysqldump`.

Comment: т.е. в том sql скрипте написать сначала  --data     --no-create-info  и --compatible=postgresql   ?

Answer (score 3):

Вот хорошая, проверенная веременем библиотека: https://github.com/maxlapshin/mysql2postgres.

Answer (score 1):

Большой набор утилит можно найти здесь https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL#MySQL